# how to search for the specific string and print its test case id using python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
************************************
     Test Scenario No. 1
     TestcaseID = FB_71125_1
     dpSettingScript = FB_71125_1_DP.txt
************************************
cp /fs/images/nfs/FileRecogTest/MNT/test/Databases/FB_71125_1_device.sqlite $NUANCE_DB_DIR/device.sqlite
    "sync" twice.

Starting the test:

            0#00041511#0000000000# FILERECNTEST: = testScenarioNo (int)1 =
         1900#00046452#0000000000# FILEREIONTESTERROR: expected <FS0000_Pos_Rec_Tone><FS1400_DeviceDisambig_<slot>_ini1>, got <FS0000_Misrec_Tone><FS1000_MainMenu_nm1_004><pause300><FS1000_MainMenu_nm_001>
            0#00046480#0000000000# FILERECNITIONTEST: Preparing test data done
            0#00047026#0000000000# FILERGNITIONTEST: Stopping dialog immediately

     Scenario 1 FAILED.

  The above is the content in my .txt file. There will several .txt file with a content as above. I want to read all those file and check.
```

1: if the Scenario FAILED then I have to print the TestcaseID of it.
I am able to read the file but I am having difficulty in checking whether the Scenario Failed and to print its test case id.
can someone guide me how to do that ?

```
directory =os.path.join("C:\Users\TEST\language")
with open(output_filename, 'w') as f_output:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory): 
        for filename in filenames:
             if filename.startswith('VCALogParser_output'): 
                cur_file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                f = open(cur_file, "r")
                a = f.read()
                # but how to search for scenario failed and how to print the respective test case id ?
            f.close()
```

Comment: Well...do you have a RegEx already? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and gives use your code (regex) which doesn't work, and explain *Why it doesn't work* in your question then. [so] isn't a code-writing service, so you need gives us *What you have tried already*.

Comment: I already solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can read the file line by line, simply:

- Read the `TestcaseID` as you find it in a line, and store that id.
- When you find a line with *Scenario X FAILED*, print the test ID you have stored.

That'd look like this:

```
with open(cur_file) as test_file:
    test_id = None
    for line in test_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('TestcaseID'):
            test_id = line.partition(' = ')[-1]
        elif line.startswith('[VCALogParser] Scenario'):
            status = line.rpartition(' ')[-1].rstrip('.')
            if status == 'FAILED':
                print(test_id)
```

I didn't even need to use regular expressions. You *can* still, but it is not a requirement to parse the sample you presented.

Comment: thanks but I am getting an error as :   File ".\framework1.txt", line 20
    if filename.startswith('VCALogParser_output'):
                                                                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: @ram: Copy my code and don't mix tabs and spaces. Configure your editor to use only spaces for indentation. My answer doesn't contain any tabs, nor does it contain indentation errors. I also used `elif` for that test so you didn't quite copy my code.

Comment: @ram: also, Python source code usually has the extension `.py`, not `.txt`.

Comment: there will several .txt file. But I have mentioned only one in my question. It should read first for english, german, chinese and so on. So I am specifying the directory and reading the .txt file one by one and checking the scenario is failed or not. if it is failed then printing the testcase id.

Comment: I think cur_file is missing in your code. i think, it is : cur_file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename). I edited my code. is it right ?

Comment: @ram: your *traceback* shows you are running this code as `framework1.txt`; that's a Python file with the `.txt` extension. I added to your code, not replaced it; your own code already defined `cur_file`.

Comment: @ram: so yes, I omitted the `cur_file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)` line; you already had that in your version but you removed it when you edited it. Just add that back in.

Comment: thanks. But how to write the test case id and filename to the output file ?

Comment: @ram: you have both `test_id` and `filename` as variables. I showed you how to detect the `FAILURE` cases. Surely you can work out from there how to write these to a file instead of printing the testcase ID?

Comment: I did that. but it is printing as shown in my code. but how to separate that from each and every other language. for example - ARW should be separate, CZC separate, DUN separate and so on.

Comment: everything is fixed but I have to make that to print in the separate format as above

Comment: Please don't keep editing your question. New problems should be posted as new questions; Stack Overflow aims to build an archive of good questions with quality answers for future visitors; it is not an interactive debugging platform.

Comment: Try to understand what my code *does*; why there is an `if` statement and when the conditions match a line, for example. You ignored the `if` statement with your code to write the test id to a file; since the `for` loop processes *every line* in the input files, you were writing something for every single line in your input file.